# Adding children to JavaFX Control/Parent classes

Tags: java, javafx

Added children used to be visible in all my subclasses, like in the example here.

Due to some recent changes I made (in a big porting of very old Java SWING code) children are still visible in `TextField` or `TextArea`, for example, but not in `Button`(ish) controls, even though additions are in the list.

Obviously, I don't understand the policy governing the addition of children. Any ideas?

```
public class QButton extends Button  {
    ...
    public QButton(String str) {
        ...
        ObservableList<Node> children = getChildren();
        System.out.println("Children: " + children);

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0., 0., 200., 200.);
        rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
        rect.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        rect.setStrokeWidth(2);
        getChildren().add(rect);
        rect.setVisible(true);

        children = getChildren();
        System.out.println("Children: " + children);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: `Added children used to be visible in all my subclasses, like in the example here.`- so you mean that the above example already worked earlier and you were able to add child nodes to a `Button`?

Comment: Yes, in the past I would see this rect in/around Button and now I don't see it any longer. In TextField I still see it.
It is in the list of children and making it "managed" explicitly doesn't help.
Making it fit inside the button doesn't help either.

Comment: That is strange, since I would expect it not to work at all: `Control` (the base class of all UI controls including `Button`) is usually rendered by delegating to a separate **Skin** object, and even though this is the `Button` itself, the skin is changing the child nodes of the Button once it is set. Try adding an event listener to your button which does `System.err.println(button.getChildrenUnmodifiable())` and you will see that the child you added in the constructor is not there anymore. Instead, there is now only one `Text` node as child

Comment: True, thanks Andreas. I had my children at the end of the constructor, but they disappeared after construction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaFX, UI Controls use the MVC (Model/View/Controller) pattern. The Control itself (e.g. a `Button`) is the Model, and rendering is delegated to the View which is called Skin in JavaFX. The node graph of the Control is maintained by the View (the Skin), hence it is not possible to simply modify the children of the Control. See https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/UI+Controls+Architecture for a good overview of the architecture.

One alternative might be to put the `Button` and the `Rectangle` into a `Group` so that the `Rectangle` overlays the `Button`, and then use the `Group` in your application's scene graph.

Otherwise, if you really want to subclass `Button` and add the `Rectangle` there, you need to create a custom skin for your `Button`. The following example shows how this can be done - one drawback is that the base skin class for Buttons (`ButtonSkin`) is not public, hence you need to extend a non-public class (which you normally should NEVER do, but I currently do not see an alternative besides duplicating a whole bunch of code from `com.sun.javafx`). In Java 9, the skin classes will be made public in the `javafx.scene.control.skin` package (see 
http://download.java.net/jdk9/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/skin/ButtonSkin.html for the `ButtonSkin`).

The following code shows how it could be done:

```
package com.example;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

// DO NOT DO THIS - com.sun is not public!
// (However, it seems that there is currently no alternative besides duplicating the code)
// With Java 9, change to javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin
class QButtonSkin extends com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ButtonSkin {

    private Rectangle rect = null;

    public QButtonSkin(Button button) {
        super(button);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateChildren() {
        super.updateChildren();

        if (rect == null) {
            rect = new Rectangle(0., 0., 200., 200.);
            rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
            rect.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            rect.setStrokeWidth(2);
        }
        getChildren().add(rect);
    }
}

public class QButton extends Button {
    public QButton(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        Skin<?> result = new QButtonSkin(this);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Essentially, `QButton` creates a new default skin (you could also do that in CSS). The new Skin overrides `updateChildren()` to add the rectangle to the control's child nodes. Here we need to consider the calling sequence - the super class's constructor calls `updateChildren()` itself, so we can not create the `Rectangle` in our Skin's constructor.

Depending on your use case, you might need to add some additional code like managing the bounds and geometry of `QButtonSkin`.

Comment: Note those skin classes will be public in Java 9, but with different package names.

Comment: Good to know - I already hoped so ... (similar to what they did with `SkinBase` in Java 8...)

Comment: Works now, thanks guys!  
  
updateChildren does the trick.  
  
I never had it although I had my skins all along (doing nothing, basically).  
  
Will update all the code but: TextFiled works now without skin, and until a few days ago Button worked also. The only difference is that I am now with newer version, albeit not much newer, of SDK/JRE